# What are the dos and don'ts related to massaging an infant?

Tags: infant, newborn, health

I was thinking of giving him a strong head massage, but then I read somewhere that newborn heads are not supposed to be touched strongly since bones aren't joint at the back of the head.

What are the dos and don'ts related to massaging an infant?

*How to hold the infant and how much pressure should be applied where?*

*If I put him on his tummy for back massage, he won't be to support his neck and his nose will be buried in the mattress. What's the way out?*

Comment: To massage the back of an infant, you can just lie him or her on your lap and gently message.

Comment: Baby massages should be **very** gentle, no strong massages of any area. When you lay him on his tummy, turn his head so that he's looking sideways. Do not put him face down, as that will suffocate him (as you point out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until the age of two the bone plates in his skull won't be fused, so yes, head massage that might move the bones would be a bad idea.  Maybe just a very gentle scalp massage instead?

As for back massage, just turn his head to the side so he can breathe freely.

Infant massage can be beneficial for everyone, so long as you move slowly, respond to his cues (if he doesn't like it, he will let you (and everyone within earshot) know :) ), and look at it as a bonding opportunity.

Most hospitals in the US (don't know your location, so I'm going by mine :> ) offer classes in infant massage. [Here's some basic info from the Mayo Clinic on infant massage.](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/infant-massage/MY01972)